# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error when I trying to make Bubble sort

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm trying to make the Bubble sort, and this is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] test = new double[5];
    double t;

    //Set random value to each of elements
    for(int i = 0;i<test.length;i++){
        test[i] = Math.round((100*Math.random()));
        System.out.println(test[i]);
    }

    //Bubble Sort
    for(int i = 0;i<test.length;i++){   

        for(int k = 0;k<test.length-1;k++){

            int x = i+1;                
            if(test[i]>test[x]){
                t = test[i];
                test[i] = test[x];
                test[x] = t;        

            }               
        }           
    }                   
  }

}
```

But then I launch it, it throws an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` goes up to the length of the array, and then you set `x` to go one past that! So, you try to access an element past the end of the array.

You can either use `i < test.length - 1` in the sort code, or otherwise check to make sure you don't try to swap the last element with the element after it.

Answer (score 1):

I think, in your inner loop, you want to be working with `k` instead of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

The line "i = x + 1;" is your problem.  When x, your counter, is 4, this takes i to 5. When you try to get the value of test[5] you go outside the bounds of the array.